# Call React Redux Toastr within a saga

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, toastr, react-intl, react-boilerplate

I'm using [React Boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate) with [React Redux Toastr](https://github.com/diegoddox/react-redux-toastr) and I want to be able to call a toastr using [React Intl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)'s messages.

I've tried to call it within a componet, but as toastr is making state updates, Reacts warns me about that as an anti-pattern. I tried too to call within a saga, but there's no way I can include Intl'messages.

```
toastr.error(formatMessage(messages.userNotFoundErrorLabel));
```

What's the best place to call a toastr with internationalization messages and making the good use of redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done within Component's componentDidUpdate function without the warning.